# How to get list of user with specific roles in MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic

How do I retrieve all the users from a specific role?

I need to remove those users from the role also.

This code only displays the roles associated with the user.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace sec="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/security" at 
"/MarkLogic/security.xqy";

sec:user-get-roles("XYZ")
```

Is there any function in MarkLogic to retrieve the users based on specific roles?

Comment: Please keep in mind that roles can be inherited. A use may still have access to a role but some other means and not show up on any APIs that only list directly attached roles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to list the users that have the role XYZ, you can use the (undocumented) function `sec:role-get-users()` and specify the role ID:

```
import module namespace sec="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/security" 
  at "/MarkLogic/security.xqy";
(: execute this against the security database :)
sec:role-get-users(xdmp:role("XYZ"))
```

If you want to remove the role XYZ from all users, you can use [`sec:remove-role-from-users()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/sec:remove-role-from-users)

```
import module namespace sec="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/security" 
  at "/MarkLogic/security.xqy";
(: execute this against the security database :)
sec:remove-role-from-users("XYZ")
```